# Using Google-Colab (python) to append to Bigquery table

Tags: python, google-bigquery, append, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use Colab to upload data to a GCP bigQuery table. However, after initial upload I am struggling to add additional data. Mainly as bq says that my data does not match schema.

I was hoping to get some help how to download table schema and use it to upload data ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Following the example from BigQuery docs:](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-get-table#bigquery_get_table-python)

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# Set table_id to the ID of the table model to fetch.
table_id = 'your-project.your_dataset.your_table'

# Make an API request.
table = client.get_table(table_id)  

# View table properties
print(f"Got table {table_id}.")
print(f"Table schema: {table.schema}")
print(f"Table description: {table.description}")
print(f"Table has {table.num_rows} rows")
```

Once you have the table schema information in hand, ensure the data you're trying to append to your table has the appropriate type and [configure a load job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data) with `bigquery.LoadJobConfig` or [stream the data into your table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) using `bigquery.Client().insert_rows_json` or `bigquery.Client().insert_rows_from_dataframe` 
See the [google-cloud-bigquery docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html) for more details on how to use those methods.

Comment: Ahh yes I forgot that in Google Collab you have to import your credentials JSON. I've been using Cloud Run/compute engine/functions where the authorization "just happens" magically from IAM permissions.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for that,

Slight change to your code.

```
# Construct a BigQuery client object.
project_id = 'gcp-project'
client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)

# Set table_id to the ID of the table model to fetch.
table_id = 'analysis.Test01'
```

I got the other bit working too. esentially i save schema to a variable, and the .to_gbq has table_schema field. What was giving me a hard time was that my table had over 50 columns and I needed some automated way to get schema

```
pandas_gbq.to_gbq(mergedDB, table_id, project_id=project_id, if_exists='append', table_schema=lcr_table_schema)

lcr_table_schema = [
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "Month",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
```